# Export Dictionary with Both Simple Values and Nested Dictionaries to CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm accessing a third-party API that returns a dictionary that contains both simple values and nested (embedded?) dictionaries. I need to convert this to a CSV file, but I need help extracting and exporting specific values from the nested dictionaries.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm getting back:

```
accounts = {
    'Id': '0131232',
    'AccountName': 'CompanyX',
    'Active': False,
    'LastModifiedBy': {'type': 'User', 'Id': '', 'Name': 'Joe Smith'}
},
{
    'Id': '987654',
    'AccountName': 'CompanyY',
    'Active': True,
    'LastModifiedBy': {'type': 'User', 'Id': '', 'Name': 'Mary Johnson'}
}
```

I'm trying to export this to a CSV file with the following code:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    dwriter = csv.DictWriter(f, accounts[0].keys())
    dwriter.writeheader()
    dwriter.writerows(accounts)

f.close()
```

What I want in the CSV file is the following:

```
Id,AccountName,Active,LastModifiedBy
0131232,CompanyX,False,Joe Smith
987654,CompanyY,True,Mary Johnson
```

What I'm *getting* with my code above is the following:

```
Id,AccountName,Active,LastModifiedBy
0131232,CompanyX,False,"{'type': 'User', 'Id': '', 'Name': 'Joe Smith'}"
987654,CompanyY,True,"{'type': 'User', 'Id': '', 'Name': 'Mary Johnson'}"
```

Obviously I need to extract the key-value pair I want from the nested dictionary and assign that value to the higher-level dictionary. My question is how do I do that while still handling the simple values as is?

It seems like this could be done with dictionary comprehension, but I'm not sure I can do a conditional with that.

Alternatively I could go through each record, check each value to see if it's a dictionary, and write out the values I want to a new dictionary, but that feels a little too heavy.

Full disclosure: I'm new to Python, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks!
- Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need `accounts` for anything else you can do:

```
for account in accounts:
    account['LastModifiedBy'] = account['LastModifiedBy']['Name']
```

otherwise, `.copy()` it and do the same.

Comment: Thanks! That was easy. Guess I was overthinking it.